# How to check whether gradle actually resolves the transitive POM dependencies?

Tags: gradle

I have a suspicion that when resolving an artifact dependencies, it ignores the dependencies declared in the POM file associated with the artifact.

How can I explore this further?

If I run grade dependencies, I just see the artifact, but no dependencies beneath it. I do see it download the POM file, and I can check in the cache that it is the right one and that has a dependencies section.

How can I debug this?

Update...

Still don't know how to find out why transitive dependencies were turned off, but turning them back on by using

```
compile("maven:coordinates:version") { transitive = true }
```

fixes the issue for me.

Comment: If `gradle dependencies` shows no transitive dependencies then Gradle is definitely not downloading anything. Can you share your build file? It's possible you might be excluding transitive dependencies.

Comment: It's rather a huge messy file... that's part of the problem...

Comment: I believe you're right. Someplace transitive dependency resolution is turned off. I can force it back on by explicitly saying "transitive = true".

Comment: A plugin might be doing it. Can you perhaps share more of your build file?

Comment: I've stumbled over https://code.google.com/p/ivyidea/issues/detail?id=36  and I noticed we use both the idea and the eclipse plugin. I am going to test with these removed. We shouldn't be using those anyways, as we chose to let intelliJ generate its project files directly from gradle, without using the plugin...

Comment: Sadly removing idea and eclipse plugins doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fell victim to https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html, artifact only notation.

Works as documented, RTFM.